# Why is this script not working how to fix it?

Tags: batch-file

need help, I wrote a script that, after selecting Yes, should combine the number of SVCHOST processes, unfortunately for reasons unknown to me, the script with the selection does not work properly, does not make changes in the registry properly, but the same code without selecting Yes or NO works perfectly or I can ask for help

a script with a choice of yes or no :

```
@echo off
mode con:cols=90 lines=30
chcp 65001
color 0C

title System Config Tool -  krok 12/x - Compress Svchost
cls
echo ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                     Compress SVCHOST?                                  ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                           [1]-YES                     [2]-NO                           ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
choice /n /c:12 /M ""
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
cls
echo ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                           Should the system make SVCHOST connection?                   ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                              WORKING...                                ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝


chcp 65001 >nul
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory"') do (set mem=%%i)
call :calc %mem%
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control" /v "SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB" /t REG_DWORD /d "%mem_kb%" /f
goto x
:calc
set "mem_gb=%~1"
set /a "mem_kb=%mem_gb%*1024*1024"
goto :eof
)ELSE IF %ERRORLEVEL%==2 (
    
goto x
)
:x
title System Config Tool  - step 13/x - End Screen
cls
echo ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                     Thank you for using the Configurator                               ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ║                   Press Enter                                                          ║
echo ║                                                                                        ║
echo ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
pause > nul
```

script without Yes or No. :

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory"') do (set mem=%%i)
call :calc %mem%
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control" /v "SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB" /t REG_DWORD /d "%mem_kb%" /f
exit
:calc
set "mem_gb=%~1"
set /a "mem_kb=%mem_gb%*1024*1024"
```

Comment: Your main issue is that you're using a label inside a parenthesized code block. Move the `:calc` labelled section to another location.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: I didn't say it was your only issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the batch-file methodology complete with all of your pointless borders etc.

This uses `powershell` to get your physical memory size in KB, instead of the very very slow `systeminfo` method together with `set /a` (whose integer math is unlikely to work with RAM over a couple of GB). I have removed the necessity for having a label within a parenthesized code block, by simply removing the unnecessary block. I have also removed the unnecessary codepage change to `65001`, because the box drawing characters should exist in the most common codepages. Finally I changed the registry key from `ControlSet001` to `CurrentControlSet`, because you have no way of knowing which contol set the end user is using.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com Con: Cols=90 Lines=30
Color 0C
Title System Config Tool -  krok 12/x - Compress Svchost
ClS
Echo ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                                    Compress SVCHOST?                                   ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                           [1]-YES                     [2]-NO                           ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12 /N
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :x
ClS
Echo ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                       Should the system make SVCHOST connection?                       ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                                       WORKING...                                       ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile
 "(Get-CimInstance -Class "Cim_PhysicalMemory" | Measure Capacity -Sum).Sum/1KB"'
) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control" /V ^
 "SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB" /T REG_DWORD /D "%%G" /F 1>NUL

:x
Title System Config Tool  - step 13/x - End Screen
ClS
Echo ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                          Thank you for using the Configurator                          ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ║                                 Press any key to close                                 ║
Echo ║                                                                                        ║
Echo ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
Pause 1>NUL
```